# What's the best way to disconnect USB printer from laptop

Tags: printing, ubuntu-drivers

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. I installed the driver for my printer/scanner And all works well. Now when I disconnect the printer from the laptop and then plug it back in it does not work. If I reboot it works and prints the job that was in the que. So what is the proper way to disconnect the printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the printer from, then click the **Enable** toggle to disable the printer.  When you're ready to use it again, right click and put the checkmark back, to toggle it back to enabled.

You can bring up the printer icon though **System Settings** -> **Printers**.